# HTML5 Polymer custom element styling with attributes

Tags: html, attributes, element, polymer

I'm trying out Polymer and custom elements. Trying to make a < h1> inside the element a certain colour by passing the attribute value. So my element code looks like this:

```
<polymer-element name="test-element" attributes="nameColor">
  <template>
    Hello! My name is <span style="color:{{nameColor}}">Robert</span>
    <h1> oioioi </h1>

  <style>
  h1 {
    color:{{nameColor}};
  }
  </style>

  </template>
  <script>

    Polymer('test-element', {
      nameColor: "blue"
    });

  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

So, then I use the element like this:

```
<test-element nameColor="red"></test-element>
```

The thing is, my name (Robert) is now red. Which is good. But the h1 element is not red. Why not? If I change color:{{nameColor}}; within the style tag to color:red; it works, but I don't want that obviously. So does the attribute value not get passed to the style? Any hints on why this is happening and where I should look for more info? I've read some blogs but don't find any specific info on this.

Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you **can** bind to `style` attributes, you **cannot** bind to `<style>` tags because of the way the CSS shimming works on non-native ShadowDOM.

It's still experimental, but take a look at [core-style](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-style).

Comment: Thanks! That was the info I was looking for. Strange thing is, this element seems to do it: https://github.com/viniciusalmeida/ninja-presentation/blob/gh-pages/src/ninja-presentation.html I couldn't get it to work properly, which is how I encountered this in the first place. Guess I'll fork it. There is a link to a demo however, which seems to work, so that's kind of weird...

Answer (score 0):

I put your code up on JSBin to see how it would work. It looks like it's shimming the CSS out to the head of the page in firefox, because the version I'm using (24 -> windows in a VM on OSX) doesn't have shadow dom support, so fails.

On Chrome 35 on OSX it keeps the shadow dom and encapsulated styles.

As a work around try the following

```
<h1 id="h1"> oioioi </h1>

Polymer('test-element', {
  nameColor: "blue",
  ready : function () {
    if (this.nameColor !== '') {
      this.$.h1.style.color = this.nameColor;
    }
  }
});
```

Which I know, is the same as doing this

```
<h1 style="color:{{nameColor}}"> oioioi </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
<span style="color:{{nameColor}}">Robert</span>
```

to

```
<span style$="color:{{nameColor}};">Robert</span>
```

and remove it form the  block and it should work.

//edit

You probably have to change:

```
Polymer('test-element', {
  nameColor: "blue"
});
```

to:

```
Polymer('test-element', {
  properties:{
    nameColor: {
      type: String,
      value: "blue"
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I tested your code in Chrome and it works but unfortunately it doesn't with FireFox and Safari !

Comment: Yeah I know that. To test the code you will need Polymer, and platform.js in case of an older browser or one that doesn't support polyfills natively (yet). This code will not work at all without that.